# AEM Mobile Content Update Handlers

Tags: cordova, adobe, aem

I am referencing the [aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink](https://github.com/blefebvre/aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink) and [aem-phonegap-starter-kit](https://github.com/blefebvre/aem-phonegap-starter-kit). I get to the point where I can export my PhoneGap application, build and run it. However, I tried adding additional images to one of my page templates. Only the image resource named `image` gets exported. All other images are ignored. If you see my content tree bellow, `image` will get exported as `page-one.img.png`, but the other two are ignored.

[image: content tree]

I started to look into the ContentSync config of [aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink](https://github.com/blefebvre/aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink) and [aem-phonegap-starter-kit] and I find these handlers getting referenced

- mobileapprootpage
- mobileapppages
- mobilepageassets
- mobilecontentlisting

I look up the [content sync documentation](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/mobile-web/contentsync.html) (I'm using 6.1) but that only makes mention of the simple handlers like `copy` and `assets`.

I looked all over the place and I can't find documentation on them. I figured that the `mobilepageassets` is what is exporting my image.

So how can I get my other images exported?

**UPDATE**

I tried to add `wcm/foundation/components/image` to a `com.day.cq.wcm.contentsync.impl.handler.PagesUpdateHandler` OSGi configuration. This had no effect.
I also tried switching my image resource types to `foundation/components/image`. That had no effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find any documentation I went and found the content update handler implementation for `mobilepageassets` and decompiled it.

A [custom handler component](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/mobile-web/contentsync.html#Implementing%20a%20Custom%20Update%20Handler) is created with

```
@Component(factory="com.day.cq.contentsync.handler.ContentUpdateHandler/identifier")
```

So to find the `mobilepageassets` implementation, I went to the [services console](http://localhost:4502/system/console/services) and did a filter lookup with

```
(component.factory=*mobilepageassets)
```

From there I was able to get the implementing class, and location of the JAR file that I downloaded and ran through the [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten) decomplier.

By looking at that source I came to understand 2 things:

1. The only reason I even got a `page-name.img.png` was because I happend to name my image resource `image` which is the same name used by the WCM page thumbnail.
2. This update handler reads its own OSGi config, which has a property for `cq.pagesupdatehandler.imageresourcetypes`.

Finally, I added the `com.adobe.cq.mobile.platform.impl.contentsync.handler.MobilePageAssetsUpdateHandler` OSGi config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    cq.pagesupdatehandler.imageresourcetypes="[wcm/foundation/components/image]"/>
```

which did get my images exported, however the paths were wrong. They got exported to a 'jcr_content' folder where the markup was looking for '__jcr_content'. I did note that in the PG starter kit & kitchen sink there was special handling for this. Instead of implementing my own image component I found `mobileapps/components/image` which was simple enough for my needs. In that case I didn't even need the OSGi config.

Answer (score -1):

Even in AEM 6.2 you can add resourceTypes of the components in OSGi console for following services:

com.adobe.cq.mobile.platform.impl.contentsync.handler.MobilePageAssetsUpdateHandler.name    -

com.adobe.cq.mobile.platform.impl.contentsync.handler.MobilePagesUpdateHandler.name -

com.adobe.cq.mobile.platform.impl.contentsync.handler.MobileRootPageUpdateHandler.name  -

com.adobe.cq.mobile.platform.impl.contentsync.handler.OffersUpdateHandler.name